# Merging two collection in Oracle, I want reassign value in collection on the basis of odd and even (comma separated)?.c1 have even & c2 have odd

Tags: oracle, plsql

current code:

```
declare
    type c is table of number;
    c1 c;
    c2 c;
    c3 c;
    a number:=0;
    b number:=0;
begin
    c1 := c(10,8,59,69,23);
    c2 := c(12,89,54,15,22);
    c3 := c1 multiset union c2;
    c1.delete;
    c2.delete;
    c1.extend(10);
    c2.extend(10);
    for i in c3.first..c3.last loop
      if mod(c3(i),2)=0 then 
        a:=a+c3(i);
      else
        b:=b+c3(i);
      end if;
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line('sum for even is '||a);
    dbms_output.put_line('sum for odd is '||b);
    dbms_output.put_line('---------------');
end;
/
```

output would be like:

```
even number's are 10,8,12,54,22
odd number's are  59,69,23,89,15
sum for even is 106
sum for odd is 255?
```

Comment: This is very unreadable please edit following to [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the Stack Overflow Help Center.

Comment: You have not asked a question.... which part of your code is producing an error/issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend collections `c1` and `c2` in a loop and add elements there:

```
declare
    type c is table of number;
    c1 c;
    c2 c;
    c3 c;
    a number:=0;
    b number:=0;
    v varchar2(4000);
begin
    c1 := c(10, 8, 59, 69, 23);
    c2 := c(12, 89, 54, 15, 22);
    c3 := c1 multiset union c2;
    c1.delete;
    c2.delete;
    for i in c3.first..c3.last loop
        if mod(c3(i),2)=0 then
            a := a + c3(i);
            c1.extend;
            c1(c1.count) := c3(i);
        else
            b := b + c3(i);
            c2.extend;
            c2(c2.count) := c3(i);
        end if;
    end loop;

    for i in 1..c1.count loop v := v || c1(i) || ', '; end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line('Even numbers: '||rtrim(v, ', '));
    v := '';
    for i in 1..c2.count loop v := v || c2(i) || ', '; end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line('Odd numbers:  '||rtrim(v, ', '));
    dbms_output.put_line('sum for even is '||a);
    dbms_output.put_line('sum for odd is  '||b);
    dbms_output.put_line('---------------');
end;
```

Result:

```
Even numbers: 10, 8, 12, 54, 22
Odd numbers:  59, 69, 23, 89, 15
sum for even is 106
sum for odd is  255
---------------
```

---

Edit - explanation:

```
c1(c1.count) := c3(i);
```

Collection `c1` was extended in previous line by one element and in this line it's filled with even number from `c3`. `c1.count` returns last index of collection

```
v := v || c1(i) || ', ';
```

In this line I'm concatenating elements from collection to a string variable `v`. This variable is next displayed as list of elements.

```
||rtrim(v, ', '))
```

From loop we got something like `1, 3, 5, 7,`, so `rtrim` is needed to remove last occurence of comma `,`.

Comment: Hi Ponder, thanks a lot for your reply, it would be grateful if  explained line no.19,27,28      ----c1(c1.count) := c3(i);                         ----------v := v || c1(i) || ', ';                             ----------||rtrim(v, ', '));       how it works

Comment: thanks a ot ponder....